# Date insertion to php table via php failing

Tags: php, mysql

i have a cart displayed and the user has to select the date of delivery from the calendar widget and click on Confirm button. on submit, the order cart should be populated along with the entered date of delivery.

the code i used is:

```
<?php
echo "<form action='' name='form1' >";

//some disaply codes here

    echo "Choose the Date of delivery<input type='date' name='date'>";


                echo "<input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' name='final_submission' value ='Confirm Order'>";
                echo "</form>";      
  ?>
```

the code for insertion is:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['final_submission'])){
                    error_reporting(E_ALL);
                    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

                        $IP="my localhost";
                        $USER="my user name";
                        $conn=mysqli_connect($IP,$USER,"","my database name");
                        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                        }


$date = stripslashes($_POST['date']);
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$query="select * from cart";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $us_id=$row['user_id'];
    $pr_id=$row['prod_id'];
    $qtty=$row['quantity'];

    $query_insert = "insert into orders(user_id, prod_id, quantity, dt_del) values('.$us_id.',
    '.$pr_id.', '.$qtty.','.$date.')";
    $res_ins=mysqli_query($conn,$query_insert);
   }
}

?>
```

the orders table s not getting populated. I cant put my finger on the error. plz point it out

EDIT: the orders table is getting poplulated, but the del date field is coming blank...Please let me know how to pass the date variable correctly, as clearly that is the issue

Comment: the dt_del is date type in the orders table

Comment: echo out `$queury_insert` and copy paste it into phpmyadmin

Comment: can you try die(mysql_error) ? that will show you the error

Comment: there is notice that i am getting "Notice: Undefined index: date"

Comment: it means your date isnt propperly set. How does your date comes in? Mostly it means the variable is empty while it requires a variable, so you need to check where the date variable comes from (i dont see it defined in your code)

Comment: thats my issue...i am just using the date input type ...and i am passing that value in the form,...please show me the correct way to do this...

Comment: Have a ***real close look*** at `echo "<form action='' name='form1' >";`

Comment: what about it? i cant point the mistake...please specify

Comment: Look at `<form action='' name='form1' >` and `$_POST` variables. The person who gave you an answer should have spotted that, which is why your form is not posting in DB. Form will default to a certain method if omitted.

Comment: yes yes..i was about to comment

Comment: just saw that mistake like 5 mins ago

Comment: You're welcome. You should tell that guy who gave you the answer, that I had to point out the error, which I did tell that person to have a look at your form again, very carefully, which he didn't. The answer shouldn't be accepted until that person made the proper addition to the answer. Because, others will visit your question and stand at downvoting the answer because of it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to attempt to be honest. Your code blocks lacks a lot of stuff. For instance:

```
$query="select * from cart";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

What results? Where do you define them? Are that results from the query you specified there, cause surely you aint executing it. Thus the result will be 0 and will not be executed.

Also the problem is with this query it will go through every row of the cart, this means also you ll grab carts that aint belonging to your costumer, specify.

So your code should be something like

```
$query="select * from cart";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
// yadi yadi yadi .. code code code
```

**edit**

Let me try to rework this out for you with propper indenting.

```
if (isset($_POST['final_submission'])){   // check if the button is correct
    // error_reporting(E_ALL);        <-- canceling this out for now
    // ini_set('display_errors', 1);  <-- canceling this out for now

       $IP="my localhost";
       $USER="my user name";
       $conn=mysqli_connect($IP,$USER,"","my database name");
       if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
           echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     }

     $date = stripslashes($_POST['date']);

     if (empty($date) || $date == ''){
          echo 'the date is not set, please check if parameter is filled in';   
     } else { // if it wont pass this point, you wont get an enormous output of unidentified indexes

         $query="select * from cart";
         $result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
             $us_id=$row['user_id'];
             $pr_id=$row['prod_id'];
             $qtty=$row['quantity'];
             $date = stripslashes($_POST['date']);  // just to play it safe define it again

             if (empty($date) || $date == ''){
                echo 'something went wrong with the date';
             }else{ 
                 $query_insert = "insert into orders(user_id, prod_id, quantity, dt_del) values('.$us_id.','.$pr_id.', '.$qtty.','.$date.')";
                 $res_ins=mysqli_query($conn,$query_insert);
             }
         }    
     }
 }
```

Comment: when the user confirms the order, all the items saved in his cart table gets copied to the orders table.and yes, i missed the exection step..i am executing the code:

$query="select * from cart";

$result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);

Comment: this is followed by the while statement

Comment: the problem with this code, as far as i understand, is with the date variable...i am new to php and this was based on what i learnt so far...please guide me to the better and correct procedure for it

Comment: but im defining code..:(   

      echo "Choose the Date of delivery<input type='date' name='date'>";

and in the insert php code I am using $date = stripslashes($_POST['date']);

Comment: No because you tell the variable outside of your while loop and it tends to forget it then. So in this case, move your `$date = stripslashes($_POST['date']);` inside your while loop. Within a while loop, you have only acces to what is returned in the result, plus everything else you define. So move your `$date` inside there and it should work.

Comment: since i was having 5 entries in the cart right now...the notice "Undefined index: date " got displayed 5 times...:(

Comment: can you type in after you defined it in the while loop `echo $date;` See what it returns.

Comment: the same notice "Notice: Undefined index: date"

Comment: Okay, this means it simply cannot be found. Your variable doesn't excist. This means somewhere in the proces your problem lies with the passing through of the date towards your php file.

Comment: I updated the code in my answer, try running it like that. If it spits out errors, it means your variable is not being passed through or passed through empty. It might be because you re using a plugin of some sort for your datepicker, i dont know this. It's a good lesson in debugging, btw.

Comment: @Dorvalla Look over OP's form again ***very carefully***

Comment: the date index is empty since it wasnt populating the column in  orders table as well...and running your code gave the same result...as i said before...there is something wrong the way date variable is being passed to the insertion php code...if you have any reference to passing of date variable in form plz guide me that way